# updating to ios5 recorder doesn't work anymore

Tags: ios5, avaudiorecorder

i have an app always working till i have installed ios5 on device.
this is the code.

```
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);    
    UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof (audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);

    //NSLog(@"url");
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/dev/null"];
    //NSLog(@"dizionario");
    NSDictionary *audioSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                   [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax],         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                   nil];
    NSError *error;    
    bool b;


    //NSLog(@"audio");
    recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:audioSettings error:&error];
    //NSLog(@"audio");
    if (recorder) {
        //NSLog(@"prepara");
        b=[recorder prepareToRecord];
        //NSLog(@"%@",(b ? @"OK" : @"NO"));
        //NSLog(@"meter");
        recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
        //NSLog(@"recorder");
        b=[recorder record];
        //NSLog(@"%@", (b ? @"OK" : @"NO"));            
        //        NSLog(@"leveltimer");
        //        levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.03 target: self selector: @selector(levelTimerCallback:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"************** ERRORE: ****************");
        NSLog([error description]);    
    }
```

the result is that recorder record silence, no peak power, no avarage power.
i use xcode4 (ios inxcode4 is till 4.3, i have not downloaded the latest xcode)
why in ios5 doesn't work anymore?
is not compatible?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have downloaded the latest xcode, tryed

Documents or Cache instead of /dev/null but no luck

i have solved but don't know why it stopped working.

the code above was putted in a singleton class loaded and initialized once at start of the app.

seems that records only one voice power then stops (even if i have controlled that recording=true, metering enabled=true ecc...in logs)

now i have putted the same code in a method of the singleton class and called that method from the file of the screen "ingame" and works...

mmm.......any ideas why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

replace the urlpath with the following code:

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Files"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];